# first and second image src is in capital letter but third image is small letter

Tags: selenium-webdriver

If first imag src is:

```
<img src="/training4.9.0/document/img/01-Express_Money_Services&amp;01-General-04-Lane_Management-STD/LM_Page_1.png" width="100%" height="auto">
```

And second img src is:

```
<img src="/training4.9.0/document/img/01-Express_Money_Services&amp;01-General-04-Lane_Management-STD/LM_Page_2.png" width="100%" height="auto">
```

And third img src is:

```
<img src="/training4.9.0/document/img/01-Express_Money_Services&amp;01-General-04-Lane_Management-STD/lm_Page_3.png" width="100%" height="auto">
```

Here first and second image in uppercase letter and third image is in small letter then how to write code for selenium webdriver. Can we use verifyImageSpl?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far. Can you provide an example?

Comment: try{
    LoggingClass.getLogger().info(
                     this.getClass().getSimpleName()
                             + "** Startind Test case : "
                             + this.getClass().getName() + "**");
  homePage = verifyPageLoad();
  LoggingClass.getLogger().info("Home page is loaded Successfully");
  TopicsPage topicsPage=homePage.navigateToHomePage(driver);
  topicsPage.navigateToRapidReload(driver,"Express Money Services");
assertTrue(topicsPage.verifyImageSpl(driver, "Lane Management","LM_Page_"));

Comment: Please edit your answer. Don't copy paste it here. It's hard to read.

Comment: assertTrue(topicsPage.verifyImageSpl(driver, "LaneManagement","LM_Page_")); we use it then first two page verify true but third page is display error.